# PDO->execute is returning a different value than odbc_exec

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, odbc, sqlsrv

I've got a database that I'm storing the results of `mcrypt_create_iv(64, MCRYPT_RAND)` in.

I am in the process of changing old code that uses `odbc_exec()` to pull data from an SQL Server to start using `PDO->execute` instead. The problem is I'm getting different values from the same column depending on what method I use.

Example:

```
odbc_exec > � ��Xr�jxM:�GF),�0qZ�Q�Z��緕Z�����8q����a���Z�9֤З�kc�
PDO->execute > þ øŽXrÝjxM:ñGF),Œ0qZÞQðZØÃç·•Z™…™ºª8qþ‘Êóa±ÒâZ°9Ö¤Ð—¢kcý
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

**odbc_exec:**

```
$dbh = odbc_connect($database,"username","password");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE uid = '$item_number'";
$results = odbc_exec($dbh,$sql);
while($row = odbc_fetch_array($results)){
    echo("$row[hashed_value]");
}
```

**PDO->execute:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE uid = :uid";
try{
    $handler = new PDO('sqlsrv:server=$server;database=$database','username','password');
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(Exception $e){
    echo($e->getMessage());
    die();
}
    
try{
    $query = $handler->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute(array(
        ":uid" => "$item_number"
    ));
        
    foreach($query as $record){
        echo($record['hashed_value']);
} catch(Exception $e){
        echo($e->getMessage());
        die();
}
```

**EDIT 2**
Each line is a separate row in the database

```
ýIÃø¹öWjÉ4‘óß‚Éb!<­EXi¢ŽåÑ‘Èp¾áù õ|©žÁÇáè¬)"²’ˆ÷èb‡<Ñ„-6Þ+

t!k°³YË1hý@¼&âBœUø—Ýõ(Ý§o|"©Œµ!3§q´çy+´ô†÷{Ô˜¥qƒþ«QÑÒ

ð]³PÚ´9·ã ‰é_»˜wÁbñÐ2|’>T/{\B/åÙ¨s¬à8†¶1Ë¬r;oënfÇ¡DQ…©x³ô>y†

-Wk|Ï^Ý¤ç«áçR>¤XE…\Ê!ÈÂ°”ÄGžd+w\,–õo?,Óq{Õ?›?E_Ù˜•  ‘¦¡Œ
```

Comment: And the two versions of the code...?

Comment: Just edited to include code sample

Comment: @Clint, could you provide some sample data and the data type of the `hashed_value` column?

Comment: @Zhorov, I've added a small sample of the data, it is stored as VARCHAR(128).

Comment: If it's a hash why isn't it in a `binary(128)` or `varbinary(128)` column? Seems like PDO is expecting a particular character encoding and is modifying your data as a result.

Comment: @Clint, you may try to change the encoding: `$handler->setAttribute(PDO::SQLSRV_ATTR_ENCODING, PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_SYSTEM);`. The default value is `PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8` and this option is driver specific.

Comment: @Clint, `$query->execute` always returns boolean. You need to fetch the data with `$query->fetch` or `$query->fetchAll`.